# schema-attribute throwing in-scope attribute declaration error

Tags: xml, xslt, xsd, schema, xslt-2.0

I am using XSLT 2.0 http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20. I have a declaration in my XSL file:

```
   <xsl:template match="schema-attribute(attr)">
            <match>schema-attribute(attr):</match>
    </xsl:template>
```

I am trying to match on schema-attribute with attr. There are multiple xml elements in my xml doc with attr as attribute.

**xml doc:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<test xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:noschemaLocation="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

  <e1>def</AAA>
  <e1 attr="1">there</AAA>
  <e1 attr="2">hey</AAA>
</test>
```

**schema**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<x:schema xmlns:x="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

    <x:element name="test" />

    <x:element name="e1" type="etype" />
    <x:complexType name="etype">
            <x:simpleContent>
                <x:extension base="x:string">
                    <x:attribute name="attr" type="x:string" use="optional"></x:attribute>
                </x:extension>
            </x:simpleContent>
    </x:complexType>
```

**xsl:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0" >
<xsl:template match="schema-attribute(attr)">
            <match>matched</match>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I get the following error:

> A sequence type expression refers to a schema attribute 'attr' that is not defined in the in-scope attribute declarations.

I dont know why the error and what it means. I tried to google but found no solution. Again, attr is a attribute in the xml too.

- What does in-scope attribute declarations mean in this specific context?
- Also, how do I use schema-attribute using the xml file above.

Comment: Your xml still makes no sense. The `xsi:schemaLocation` should be a sequence of namespace/schema pairs. Since your document doesn't use a namespace you probably want `xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation` instead.

Comment: ok I made those changes. but how can I use schema-attribute with this xml doc?

Comment: Are you just trying to figure out how to match the `attr` attribute? If so, the match expression for your template would be `<xsl:template match="@attr">`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I could try a much briefer response than Michael Sperberg-McQueen: schema-attribute() tests are very rarely useful. They only match attributes that have been validated against global (top-level) attribute declarations in a schema, and very few schemas actually use global attribute declarations. Most, like yours, define attributes in local declarations.

The error message means your schema does not have a global attribute declaration called "attr".

You ask: "Also, how do I use schema-attribute() using the xml file above.". That's not a good question. There are very few problems for which schema-attribute() is a solution. I suspect that your problem is not one of them. Tell us what you are trying to do, and we can tell you how to go about solving it. Choose the tools to match the problem, not the problem to match the tools.

Comment: Could you tell me 1 problem where schema-attribute can be useful as you mentioned there are only a few cases where it can be?

Comment: I cannot understand from the spec what is schema-attribute at the first place? If you could atleast tell me what it means? then i can probably come up with better questions matching my scenario

Comment: schema-attribute(A) matches an attribute node if (1) it is named "A", (2) there is a global attribute declaration in the schema named "A", (3) the attribute node has been validated against the schema, and (4) the attribute node has a type that is consistent with the type defined in the global attribute declaration.

Comment: Regarding your first question, I don't think I have ever used schema-attribute() in anger, but it could in theory be useful for handling global attributes such as xml:space, where a template rule with match="schema-attribute(xml:space)" would not match any attribute named xml:space, but only one that has been schema-validated against the schema definition of xml:space.